Must all checksum links expire after the same interval?
Can some checksum links be set not to expire?  Or can some checksum links expire in 7 days, and some in 30 days?  Is it really dangerous to let them last too long?
[CiviCRM 5.78.3 on Wordpress]

You can choose how long checksum links are valid for, but all links share the same value.  See Checksum Lifespan
